# Orient db distributed database configuration

Tags: orientdb

I am unable to configure distributed databases using https://github.com/orientechnologies/orientdb/wiki/Tutorial%3A-setup-a-distributed-database

I am using orientdb community 1.7.5 edition.
The nodes aren't able to connect to each other. I am configuring it on same server and have followed each and every instruction given in above link.

Update:
there weren't any error earlier however got this error last time when I tried.
here aren't any errors earlier. but got below error last time when I tried...

```
00:55:15:315 INFO [152.144.227.223]:2434 [orientdb] [3.2.2] Accepting socket connection from /152.144.227.223:56818 [SocketAcceptor]
2014-07-23 00:55:15:321 INFO [152.144.227.223]:2434 [orientdb] [3.2.2] 2434 accepted socket connection from /152.144.227.223:56818 [TcpIpConnectionManager]
2014-07-23 00:55:16:321 WARN [152.144.227.223]:2434 [orientdb] [3.2.2] Invalid join request from: Address[152.144.227.223]:2435, reason:Incompatible joiners!  -vs- tcp-ip [ClusterService]
2014-07-23 00:55:16:325 INFO [152.144.227.223]:2434 [orientdb] [3.2.2] Connection [Address[152.144.227.223]:2435] lost. Reason: Socket explicitly closed [TcpIpConnection]
```

also find below the hazlecase configuration.its same for both nodes. nodes are on same machine.

```
<network>
        <port auto-increment="true">2434</port>
        <join>
            <multicast enabled="false">
                <multicast-group>235.1.1.1</multicast-group>
                <multicast-port>2434</multicast-port>
            </multicast>
        </join>
        <tcp-ip enabled="true">
        <member>152.144.227.223:2434</member>
        <member>152.144.227.223:2435</member>
        </tcp-ip>
    </network>

tried by changing the port in hazlecast to 152.144.227.223:2424/2425 and got below warning when starting node1.
2014-07-23 01:14:27:157 INFO null [orientdb] [3.2.2] Picked Address[152.144.227.223]:2434, using socket ServerSocket[addr=/0:0:0:0:0:0:0:0,localport=2434], bind any local is true [DefaultAddressPicker]
2014-07-23 01:14:27:252 INFO [152.144.227.223]:2434 [orientdb] [3.2.2] Hazelcast Community Edition 3.2.2 (20140527) starting at Address[152.144.227.223]:2434 [system]
2014-07-23 01:14:27:254 INFO [152.144.227.223]:2434 [orientdb] [3.2.2] Copyright (C) 2008-2014 Hazelcast.com [system]
2014-07-23 01:14:27:258 INFO [152.144.227.223]:2434 [orientdb] [3.2.2] Address[152.144.227.223]:2434 is STARTING [LifecycleService]
2014-07-23 01:14:27:424 WARN [152.144.227.223]:2434 [orientdb] [3.2.2] No join method is enabled! Starting standalone. [Node]
2014-07-23 01:14:27:457 INFO [152.144.227.223]:2434 [orientdb] [3.2.2] Address[152.144.227.223]:2434 is STARTED [LifecycleService]
```

**NEW ERROR**

getting below error on both nodes

```
2014-08-08 16:27:37:309 INFO [192.168.159.134]:2434 [orientdb] [3.2.2] Hazelcast Community Edition 3.2.2 (20140527) starting at Address[192.168.159.134]:2434 [system]
2014-08-08 16:27:37:309 INFO [192.168.159.134]:2434 [orientdb] [3.2.2] Copyright (C) 2008-2014 Hazelcast.com [system]
2014-08-08 16:27:37:356 INFO [192.168.159.134]:2434 [orientdb] [3.2.2] Address[192.168.159.134]:2434 is STARTING [LifecycleService]
2014-08-08 16:27:38:494 WARN [192.168.159.134]:2434 [orientdb] [3.2.2] No join method is enabled! Starting standalone. [Node]
2014-08-08 16:27:38:869 INFO [192.168.159.134]:2434 [orientdb] [3.2.2] Address[192.168.159.134]:2434 is STARTED [LifecycleService]
```

Comment: What's the problem? Are you using Windows? Do you have logs?

Comment: @Lvca its windows. there aren't any errors earlier. updated original post with error details.

Comment: By reading the logs problem this is a Hazelcast problem: "Invalid join request from: Address[152.144.227.223]:2435, reason:Incompatible joiners!  -vs- tcp-ip". Double check all the nodes have the same configuration. See also: http://hazelcast.org/docs/3.1/manual/html/ch14s02.html#ConfigSpecifyInterfaces

Comment: @Lvca am getting the new set of errors .. just cant get it right .. updated the original post with new error.

Comment: Please upgrade to 1.7.7.

Comment: @Lvca I upgraded to 1.7.7 and tried with default configuration. it didn't work.

Comment: Look at the error: "No join method is enabled! Starting standalone" means you have to specify or multicast or direct ip. So enable at least one of these.

Answer (score 1):

To be able to form clusters you need to add tcp-ip tag inside the join tag of the hazelcast configuration. The error which you are facing because of No join method will be resolved. Your hazelcast configuration file should look like this:

```
    <join>
        <multicast enabled="false">
            <multicast-group>235.1.1.1</multicast-group>
            <multicast-port>2434</multicast-port>
        </multicast>
  <tcp-ip enabled="true">
            <member>152.144.227.223:2434</member>
            <member>152.144.227.223:2435</member>
        </tcp-ip>
    </join>
```